# Keyboard stopped functioning for no apparent reason

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, hardware-failure

I was just typing in Firefox when **my keyboard stopped working**. I couldn't type in any program. **After a reboot, however, my keyboard works fine.**

Why would my keyboard spontaneously stop functioning? How could I determine the cause?

**I do not have a wireless keyboard. I'm using only the embedded keyboard on my laptop.**

Possible Windows 7 x64 issue? Or just a weird anomaly?

**Note:** If at all possible, I do not want to spend any money on taking it to a repair shop. It'd much rather have it fixed myself.

**EDIT - 7/7/11:** The function keys seem to be working. I can still toggle the backlight on my monitor with `Fn + F8`.

**EDIT - 7/13/11:** I have to use my wireless keyboard whenever my laptop keyboard stops functioning.

Comment: Anything...sh*t happens.

Comment: Did it happen only once? If so, it may be a random issue caused by curiosity. If it happens more often, than its a hardware issue that you won't be able to fix by yourself. It may also be a strange kind of virus, but I never heard of one with those symptomatic.

Comment: @Michael No, it's happened on multiple occasions. I'm thinking it might be some type of malware, but what would stopping my keyboard from working hope to achieve? Other than frustrating myself by having to restart or use the On-Screen keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably a hardware issue . This usually happens in desktops where keyboard is connected via ps/2 port and the motherboard doesnot support hotswapping and the wire gets accidently dislodged . Wait for this to happen again and then take your laptop for an inspection